# Changing the hostname to the url, configuration in apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i have in ubuntu an apache server with a web in /var/www/myweb. I have a domain in internet (f.e: http://www.calamaricodomain.com) in the provider i have redirect to my static ip. All is correct, i put www.calamaricodomain.com in webrowser and my page shows, but the URL of the browser change to my static IP, and i do not want that, i think that can be configured in Apache, anyone knows where can change it?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was madeing for my dns provider, it was a problem with the 'A records' and 'CNAME records'